# Restrict search results from outside the web application

Tags: 2010, search

I have a single search service application associated with both of my web applications. In each web application I want search results to only appear from within that web application.

I believe I can create a second search service application and dedicate one per web app but that seems overkill. Is there a straightforward solution using Search Scopes or other features? I am not particularly familiar with search configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the CA level:
If you want to do this at the central admin level, then I think your options are pretty limited. You can create seperate content sources for search and use rules to minimise but I think this will not work very well.

At the site collection level:
If you donot require scope drop down to appear on the site then change the search settings Under Site Actions > Search settings > Site Collection Search Dropdown Mode > Set it to " Do not show scopes dropdown, and default it to contextual scope".

At the search web part level:
You can configure the core search results web part to minimise the search scope, here is how to do this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549987%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

Hope it helps.